# Different screen capture approach comparison (incl. BitBlt, CopyFromScreen, DirectX, PrintScreen) in C#

Tags: c#, performance, screen, capture

I've been experimenting with screen capture  for a couple of days and tried many different approaches.

So far I like SlimDX (DirectX for .Net) method the most, because it allows me to capture not just stationary objects, but also "transparent" and "DX overlay" objects (i.e. **everything** that happens on the screen). The downside is that it takes quite a while to make a single screenshot (80-90ms for Surface capture + 110ms for Surface->Bitmap conversion + 600ms (optional) for Bitmap exporting/saving = 800ms-1s total)

BitBlt doesn't capture "DX overlays" from my display.. However it's performance is higher.

PrintScreen - too easy ;)

CopyFromScreen.. I don't remember much about it.. but it had problems just like BitBlt.

So the point is - if you don't need extra features you might use faster approaches. Now for the question - I don't know much about Security or better to say "Privacy" of these methods. For my research, I need to protect the fact of "screen capture" from troyans, rootkits, programs that are possibly spying on my "actions". This is a crucial condition for me.

I know that PrintScreen is easily detectable because it simulates PrintScreen button push. It this case hook (?not sure?) might expose my screen capture action. Both BitBlt and CopyFromScreen also don't seem too reliable to me.. Everything that's left is SlimDX. As far as I understand it captures screenshot from video card front(maybe back)buffer.

So what do you guys think about "privacy protection" of these methods? Which one is more secure?

P.S.: If I wanted to have performance I would have spammed BitBlt every 10ms and lived long and happily, but for my research I need the most versatile and secure method, so I don't mind spending 400ms for a screen capture ;) cheers.

Comment: Sounds like you're setting up a "troyan, rootkits, programs that are possibly spying on [their] "actions" program yourself.

Comment: @MichaelTodd I'm doing it for my research paper. And no, an average person wouldn't notice BitBlt, CaptureFromSreen screen capture 99,999% of a time. I, on the other side - choose slow methods, unusable for spying, see how your assumption is wrong here?

Comment: secure from detection is what you want?  They should all be I'd guess.